# paypal IPN sends two different twice

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I've come across something a bit strange I was hoping someone with more experience with Paypal can explain, Specifically the IPN feature.

It seems I'm getting two very different hits to my IPN listener. The first one always fails, The second one passes.

Now I know Paypal tends to send duplicates, But what I've noticed is two very different $_POST arrays being recieved.

Here's the respones :

```
    [2014-06-08 23:51:19] 
    RAW POST DATA : Array
    (
            [transaction] => Array
            (
                    [0] => ILS 20.00
            )

            [payment_request_date] => Sun Jun 08 13:52:12 PDT 2014
            [return_url] => MY_URL
            [fees_payer] => EACHRECEIVER
            [ipn_notification_url] => MY_URL
            [sender_email] => patrick.testbuyer@gmail.com //fake email
            [verify_sign] => ANp5TpLat3.2ylx.cECtVZ..5HejAsVcs05tdVC7RldmeYNJ91SKaqFJ
            [test_ipn] => 1
            [cancel_url] => MY_URL
            [pay_key] => AP-04B74091M7083584A
            [action_type] => PAY
            [transaction_type] => Adaptive Payment PAY
            [tracking_id] => 13 // This is a number I passed, But it doesn't exist in the 2nd POST
            [status] => COMPLETED
            [log_default_shipping_address_in_transaction] => false
            [charset] => windows-1252
            [notify_version] => UNVERSIONED
            [reverse_all_parallel_payments_on_error] => false
    )

    [2014-06-08 23:51:19]
    RAW POST DATA :  Array
    (
            [transaction_subject] =>
            [payment_date] => 13:52:28 Jun 08, 2014 PDT
            [txn_type] => web_accept
            [last_name] => test
            [residence_country] => US
            [item_name] =>
            ....

            (this continues for quite a bit more)

            ....
            [payment_fee] =>
            [mc_fee] => 1.78
            [mc_gross] => 20.00
            [custom] =>
            [charset] => windows-1252
            [notify_version] => 3.8
            [ipn_track_id] => f93ce8bdd4382
    )
```

**My problem**
The first IPN with the juicy `tracking_id` fails, the 2nd IPN is verified, But once the IPN is verified I no longer have access to the `tracking_id`.

**My questions**
Why does paypal send two different IPN's
Why are they different?
Why isn't any of this documented on Paypal? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working with Adaptive Payments, so you need to make sure you always remember that there are 3 parties in play:  the application itself, the sender, and the receiver.

Many times your application may act as the sender or receiver, too, but in other cases it may be 3 entirely separate parties.

The IPN system is setup to send the application an IPN, which is the first one you've shown here, and then the receiver account would get an IPN as well for the payment they just received, which is the second IPN you're getting.  You can process these accordingly based on the transaction_type / txn_type values that you get in them.

This way when you build apps that work on behalf of 3rd party users you can track things at the app level and receivers can still get their own IPN for tracking and processing their own transactions.  You're acting as both so you're getting both.

If one of them is failing then you must have an issue in the script that causes that particular type to fail.  You can check your web server logs to see what the actual error was and then get it resolved.

Another thing I like to do is replicate the IPN in my own simulator using a basic HTML form with the action set to my IPN URL.  Set hidden fields with the same names/values you get from a real PayPal IPN that failed, and then load that in a browser and submit it so you can see the result on screen.  This can be useful in debugging.

Just keep in mind that when you test this way the data is not coming from PayPal so it will not verify correctly, but you can get everything in order around that and then you'll be ready to go.

Comment: Thanks andrew! Is it just me or the first IPN, sent to the application isn't really used for anything useful. I don't even need the first IPN, As I do all my validation on the 2nd. this is also why the first one fails, All the fields I use to validate against don't exist in the first IPN, so it doesn't pass my screening. Is there a way to to have two different URLS for the IPN listeners? one for the application and one for the receiver?

Comment: If you built an application for other people to send and receive money through then you might want the app specific IPN's to track usage of your app, for example, even though you have nothing to do with the actual transactions.  For your scenario, it sounds like you must be setting the NotificationURL parameter in your Pay request..??  Have you tried just removing that?

Comment: I just realized i was setting it! Thanks a bunch